# Is this Peter Below code a memory leak?

Tags: delphi

I know I should not question Peter Below, but I just found this code snippet [Text File Size](http://delphidabbler.com/tips/166) when trying to debug some old D5 code.

It seems to me that the Sysutils.FindClose should be called as the last line of the function. If the Result is zero, doesn't that leave the FindFirst established and hanging?

More questions: It states this is for Text files, but couldn't this be used for any file type? A better Delphi.FileSize(fname : string); ?

```
function TextfileSize(const name: string): LongInt;
var
  SRec: TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(name, faAnyfile, SRec) = 0 then
  begin
    Result := SRec.Size;
    Sysutils.FindClose(SRec);
  end
  else
    Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: 1) No. You need to call `FindClose` only if `FindFirst` succeeds. 2) Sure, it's for any file type. 3) What is `FileSize` with such prototype ?

Comment: You can question anyone. At least you will learn something.

Comment: FWIW, in a version later than Delphi 5, IIRC, `FindClose` was modified thus that you ***can*** always call it, even if `FindFirst` failed, but you **don't have to**.

Answer (score 7):

> It seems to me that the Sysutils.FindClose should be called as the last line of the function. If the Result is zero, doesn't that leave the FindFirst established and hanging?

No. You do not need to call `FindClose` if `FindFirst` failed. For modern versions of Delphi it is safe to call it irrespective of the outcome of `FindFirst`. For older versions of Delphi the conditional code in the question was needed. No matter, there is no leak here.

Unfortunately the documentation does not make this clear. The only way to be sure of this is to read the source code.

> It states this is for Text files, but couldn't this be used for any file type?

This function operates in exactly the same manner for all types of file.

> A better Delphi.FileSize(fname : string); ?

I don't know which function you are referring to, but the function in your question has two weaknesses. Firstly it returns a 32 bit signed integer and so gives erroneous output for files larger than 2GB. And secondly it reads the file size from the filesystem metadata which may not always match the true file size. That latter issue may not be something that you should be concerned with. It is often quite reasonable to use the file size stored in the filesystem metadata.

Answer (score 4):

`FindClose` only needs to be called if `FindFirst` is successful, as indicated by its return value 0. That's exactly what he does here.. See [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=FindFirst) or in the Delphi help file.

And indeed, it works for all kinds of files, not just text files.

Answer (score 0):

> If the Result is zero, doesn't that leave the FindFirst established and hanging?

No.  `FindFirst()` returns an error code, where 0 means success, not failure.  `TextFileSize()` does not exit immediately when its `Result` is assigned a value, the code keep running.  So, if `FindFirst()` is successful, `Result` is assigned the files size value, and `FindClose()` is then called correctly to cleanup the `TSearchRec` and close the search handle, as expected.